# rename function on live db to match local db

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm having trouble with a table function i created in sqlserver 2008.

I created it in my local db and it appears as:

**[dbo].MyFunction** when i view it in management studio.

but when i create the function on the live db (im using shared hosting btw) it appears as:

**[myusername].MyFunction** when i view it in management studio.

This is causing me problems as I am using sqlmetal to generate classes based on the db.
I'd rather the names were consistent for both db's

How can I rename it? as i tried modifying it but tthat didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following statement (with a user which has sufficient permissions)

```
exec sp_rename '[myusername].MyFunction', '[dbo].MyFunction'
```

When your user is not member of the db_owner role, any object your create without specifying the schema will be created in your "user schema"

To prevent this in the future, create your function as:

```
create function dbo.MyFunction()
returns ...
```

Comment: the rename did not work for me - however deleting and recreating as in the second part did work. thanks